# Taking pictures of glass for a local Glass Gallery

Tags: canon, lighting, macro, studio-lighting, glass

I am currently trying to take pictures of a variety of high end pipes for a local glass gallery and am having a tough time getting full white accent lights from top to bottom, the light is either to harsh off the bounce card or doesn't cover the whole piece, any tips?

Comment: Please provide example photos of what you've tried, and if possible, can you point to something you're trying to emulate?

Comment: Related: [Taking a still life photo of glass bottles with two flashes](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/88540)

Comment: Related: [Shooting glass product with embossment](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/77376)

Comment: Related: [How to film translucence and light?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/46740)

Answer (score -3):

I'm at work at the moment so I can't give a full reply, but I hope this YouTube video, [Broncolor 'How To' shoot engraved glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDs2GoTjkeE), will help.

Would be good to know what kind of setup you're using for this currently.

Comment: Stack Exchange strongly frowns upon link-only answers - please expand this answer to include the key points from the video.